# Did Rome attempt to justify its conquests?

Tags: conquest, rome

In college, a history professor said they did not -- maybe (not sure if I recall correctly) that ideas like that are modern and Rome wanted the slaves and treasure and so they just went ahead.

EDIT: Seems clear enough but what I meant was, Did Rome suggest that they were doing it for national security or to spread civilization or to prevent the domino-like expansion of the Gauls or whatever?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate on what to "justify its conquests" means and how it is justified with examples and references?

Comment: Why would Rome justify activity that every state viewed as the normal, natural behavior of a state?

Comment: Some conservative senators wanted to charge Julius Caesar for waging an "illegal war" against the Gauls (or the Germanic tribes, can't remember well).

Comment: On my opinion, the question makes sense, as stated. I answered and nominated to reopen.

Comment: This is a good question too. The first answer is no. This was Rome, they were Romans you were not. But I would argue from my albeit limited reading on the subject that unlike most "conquerors" there was always an attempt to engage in discussions with their adversaries and enemies alike. I would not call it Diplomacy per se but certainly to be Roman was to be engaged. They certainly weren't the Mongols for example.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace -- The old "asking a dog to justify breathing" cliche? Seriously, Rome was a nation made up of people and some of them, if they were anything like modern people, which they well may have not been in this respect, might have said, Why is this being done? Why are we bothering these other nations? But according to one history prof, they did not.

Comment: `Rome wanted the slaves and treasure and so they just went ahead` Economics is economics, but ideology is ideology. Yes, they needed treasures, yet they always justified their wars by some reason. Seems like "national security" was the most usual type of argument.

Comment: Ideology changes over time.  During the Roman era the only way to earn wealth was through conquest.  They didn't need to justify the war, because the war made Rome more wealthy and improved the lives of Romans.  They believed the world was zero sum and the only way to advance was by taking wealth from others. They did not have the modern concept that nations were equal; strong nations took from the weak and Rome was the strongest.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace `Why would Rome justify activity that every state viewed as the normal, natural behavior of a state?` What's effectively being asked is, Did Rome publicly state any Casus Belli for their offensive wars? It's more of a modern concept. One reason for Casus Belli today is to prevent other powerful nations from interfering with your war, or maybe even get them to help you. Back in those days, I don't think there was any other power that could meaningfully interfere with Rome.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, they did. They argued that their conquests bring benefits of peace, civilization and prosperity to the conquered lands. This point of view was expressed not only by native Roman writers (like Cicero) but also by some writers from the conquered nations (Polybius, for example).

In the case of Greece, they certainly did not bring civilization to Greece, just the opposite happened. But they brought peace. The whole history of ancient Greece is the history of continuous cruel warfare between the city-states. And all
attempts to stop it and unite the Greek states before the Roman conquest failed.
Writers of that time perfectly understood that "Greek freedom is essentially the freedom to
make war on each other", I don't remember which (Greek) writer said that.

The same argument was used by
some British empire builders (The "burden of white man" as Kipling called it). Some modern scientists agree with this argument,
for example:

Ian Morris, War! What is it good for?: Conflict and the Progress of Civilization from Primates to Robots, 2014.

EDIT. I do not say anything about the plausibility of this argument, but this was not asked. In some cases indeed it looks like Roman conquest brought peace (Greece). In other cases it led to complete destruction of the conquered society (Carthage).

Comment: Good answer too. Interesting the impact Christianity had on Rome though. And vice versa actually. Certainly one we live with today.

Comment: @user14394: What does this have to do with either the question or the answer? By the time Christianity became an issue, Rome was already at / beyond maximum expansion.

Comment: @user14394: Christianity became the state religion only in 4th century, when conquests were already far in the past.